# Time complexity of Simpson's rule for simple intergral calculus

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I am looking for a reference and a proof for the time complexity of Simpson's rule for integral calculus. 
I am not sure if the class complexity of that rule belongs to `O(N)`.

Could you point me out to the right direction ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the Simpson's Rule requires three inputs:

- The function `f(x)`, assume it takes `O(1)` time.
- The bounds of integration `(a, b)`
- The number of subdivisions, n. Then the width of the "bar" `d = (b - a) / n` Note `n` must be an even positive integer.

Simpson's Rule states that

∫<sub>a</sub><sup>b</sup> f(x) ≈ (d/3)([f(x<sub>0</sub>) + f(x<sub>n</sub>)] + [2f(x<sub>1</sub>) + 4f(x<sub>2</sub>)] + [2f(x<sub>3</sub>) + 4f(x<sub>4</sub>)] + ... [2f(x<sub>n-2</sub>) + 4f(x<sub>n-1</sub>)])

∫<sub>a</sub><sup>b</sup> f(x) ≈ (d/3)([f(x<sub>0</sub>) + f(x<sub>n</sub>)] + ∑<sub>k=2</sub><sup>(n-1)/2</sup> f(x<sub>k</sub>)

where x<sub>k</sub> is equal to a + kd. Note x<sub>0</sub> = a, x<sub>n</sub> = a + nd = b.

From the summation term ∑<sub>k=2</sub><sup>(n-1)/2</sup>, we can easily state that there are `[(n-1)/2 - 2 + 1]` terms, and there are also two more terms for f(x<sub>0</sub>), f(x<sub>n</sub>). The number of terms used for the Simpson rule for a given n is **linear** to n.

Assuming multiplication is constant and the function complexity is constant, we note the summation formula to determine that the time complexity of the Simpson rule is `O(n)`, it runs in linear time.